# Extract IP CIDR from a text file

Tags: batch, notepad++, batch-file, regex

I have a large text file like this:

```
103.195.100.0/22     ReliableSite.Net LLC   1,024
103.214.69.0/24  Gestion DBI    256
103.238.80.0/22  Cloudone Technology Company Limited    1,024
103.43.72.0/22   Choopa, LLC    1,024
104.128.72.0/23  ReliableSite.Net LLC   512
...
```

and I only want to save IP CIDR like `103.195.100.0/22`.
Searched the internet and tried some ways but didn't work.

Comment: What regular expression have you used, and why did it fail?

Comment: @mtak `/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})/g`with newline checked but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx replace:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\/[0-9]+)(.+)
```

to:

```
\1
```

*RegEx of course might be better...*

[Notepad++ regular expressions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

[image: Notepad++ RegEx replace dialog]

Comment: Worked thanks. Isn't there any other ways to just export all `ip/nn` from a web page? I use this website to get ranges: https://ipinfo.io/AS20473

Comment: If your browser have console, you can write java script function to extract this information directly from webpage...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using shorter regex:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/\d+\K.*$`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : Beginning of line
(?:         : start non capture group
  \d{1,3}   : 1 upto 3 digits
  \.        : a dot
){3}        : end capture group, must appear 3 times
\d{1,3}     : 1 upto 3 digits
/           : a slash
\d+         : 1 or more digits
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
.*$         : rest of the line, 0 or more any character but newline
```

**Result for given example:**

```
103.195.100.0/22
103.214.69.0/24
103.238.80.0/22
103.43.72.0/22
104.128.72.0/23
```